# Creating a DiGraph using networkx

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
  Name   Project  Start_date

0 Joe    A        01/01/2022
1 Joe    B        03/01/2022
2 Joe    C        07/01/2022
3 Fred   A        01/01/2022
4 Fred   D        05/01/2022
5 Fred   C        08/01/2022
```

For each Name, the list is ordered by Start_date. I want to create a directed graph using `networkx` where nodes are Projects, and the edges are labeled with Name and connectivity between nodes is ordered by the Start_date. So for example:

A ->Joe-> B ->Joe-> C

I looked at using something like:

```
projects = df['Project'].to_list()
nx.read_adjlist(projects, create_using=nx.DiGraph)
```

But I can not seem to get it working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following (`df` your dataframe):

```
df.Start_date = pd.to_datetime(df.Start_date)  # Just to make sure
df = df.sort_values("Start_date")
df["Next_Project"] = df.groupby("Name").Project.shift(-1)
```

This sets up the dataframe for using [`nx.from_pandas_edgelist()`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.convert_matrix.from_pandas_edgelist.html):

```
   Name Project Start_date Next_Project
0   Joe       A 2022-01-01            B
1   Joe       B 2022-03-01            C
2   Joe       C 2022-07-01          NaN
3  Fred       A 2022-01-01            B
4  Fred       B 2022-04-01            D
5  Fred       D 2022-05-01            C
6  Fred       C 2022-08-01          NaN
```

Then read it into a [`nx.MultiDiGraph`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/classes/multidigraph.html), because nodes could have multiple edges (I have adjusted your example to add such a case):

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(
    df[df.Next_Project.notna()],
    source="Project", target="Next_Project", edge_attr="Name",
    create_using=nx.MultiDiGraph,
    edge_key="Name"
)
```

Edges and nodes:

```
OutMultiEdgeView([('A', 'B', 'Joe'), ('A', 'B', 'Fred'), ('B', 'C', 'Joe'), ('B', 'D', 'Fred'), ('D', 'C', 'Fred')])
NodeView(('A', 'B', 'C', 'D'))
```